# Import web data in Excel without overwriting history

Tags: excel, web-scraping, excel-import

I'm importing data into excel from an online phone log. It basically looks like this:

```
Date        Time    Duration    Local Identity          Number
14.12.2016  11:11   00:03       88821354@192.168.1.2    22252797
14.12.2016  10:33   00:02       88821354@192.168.1.2    25322678
```

I've successfully imported the data into Excel. However, the phone log itself is really annoying in that it only keeps data from the most recent call to any given number. I.e. if I make a call to the second number on the list above (25322678), I will lose the data on the previous call (made at 10:33). And this will be mirrored in Excel.

I am wondering whether there's a way to continuosly import new data without overwriting the old. It seems to me like there's no way of doing this by tweaking the import settings, so I'm considering different workarounds. I haven't been able to come up with anything remotely capable of this yet though.

Comment: Any chance you could provide the code you are using so that we can have some idea what's happening and offer advice from there?

Comment: where is the data taken from? do you run any software to keep track of the data? are you backing up? with three lines of requirement nothing can be done!

Comment: No code is being used here. Merely using the "From web" function in Excel and point at an IP address only locally accessible. That part is working just fine. The problem is that the "From web" function mirrors the content present at any given time at the IP address, and as I've described above, this content is volatile. What I'm looking for is some kind of workaround that would be able to "lock" the data once it's in Excel. I'm sorry if it's still not clear - I'm struggling to find more words to describe the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution creates a worksheet named *“PhoneLog”* to hold the accumulated results of the *"From web"* function.

This procedure assumes that the results of the *"From web"* function are located in a worksheet named *“WebFrom”* in range `A:E` starting at row `1` *(change as required)*

This procedure must be located in the same workbook holding the results of the *"From web"* function.

Run this procedure the first time *before* updating the *"From web"* function in order to add the actual results to the "PhoneLog". Thereafter run this procedure immediately after the *"From web"* function.

This procedure creates the *“PhoneLog”* worksheet if it’s not found in the workbook. Then it adds to *“PhoneLog”* all new records from the *“WebFrom”* worksheet *(change as required)*.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Phone_Log()
Const kWebFrom As String = "WebFrom"    'change as required
Const kPhoneLog As String = "PhoneLog"  'change as required
Dim wshWeb As Worksheet, wshLog As Worksheet
Dim blwshNew As Boolean
Dim rWeb As Range, rLog As Range
Dim aWeb As Variant, vItm As Variant
Dim lRow As Long, l As Long

    Rem Set Worksheets
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wshWeb = .Worksheets(kWebFrom)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wshLog = .Worksheets(kPhoneLog)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If wshLog Is Nothing Then
            blwshNew = True
            Set wshLog = .Worksheets.Add(After:=wshWeb)
            wshLog.Name = kPhoneLog
    End If: End With

    Rem Set FromWeb Array
    With wshWeb
        If Not (.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then .Cells(1).AutoFilter
        Set rWeb = .Cells(1).CurrentRegion
    End With
    With rWeb
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        Set rWeb = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        aWeb = .Offset(1).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    Rem Set Log Array
    With wshLog
        If blwshNew Then
            Rem Set Log - First Time
            rWeb.Copy
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit

        Else
            Rem Add New Records into Log Range
            Set rLog = .Cells(1).CurrentRegion
            With rLog
                lRow = .Rows.Count
                For l = 1 To UBound(aWeb)
                    vItm = WorksheetFunction.Index(aWeb, l, 0)

                    'Use this line if running the "FromWeb" function for one IP address only
                    'If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), vItm(1), _
                        .Columns(2), vItm(2), .Columns(5), vItm(5)) = 0 Then
                    'Use this line if running the "FromWeb" function for several IP addresses
                    If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), vItm(1), _
                        .Columns(2), vItm(2), .Columns(4), vItm(4), .Columns(5), vItm(5)) = 0 Then

                        lRow = 1 + lRow
                        .Rows(lRow).Value = vItm
            End If: Next: End With

            Rem Format Log Range
            Set rLog = .Cells(1).CurrentRegion
            With rLog
                .Rows(2).Copy
                .Offset(1).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                .Columns.AutoFit
            End With

            Rem Sort Log Range
            With .Sort
                .SortFields.Clear
                .SortFields.Add Key:=rLog.Columns(1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                    Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SortFields.Add Key:=rLog.Columns(2), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                    Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                'Use also this line if running the "FromWeb" function for several IP addresses
                .SortFields.Add Key:=rLog.Columns(4), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                    Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SetRange rLog
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply

    End With: End If: End With

End Sub
```

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[Excel Objects](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Objects.html), 
[For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264596.aspx), 
[If...Then...Else Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251599.aspx),

[On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx), 
[Option Explicit Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278855(v=office.15).aspx),

[Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), 
[Range.CurrentRegion Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678(v=office.15).aspx), 
[Range.Offset Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx),

[Range.PasteSpecial Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476(v=office.15).aspx), 
[Range.SpecialCells Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx),

[Using Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251519.aspx), 
[Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html), 
[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx), 
[Workbook Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff835568.aspx),

[Worksheet.AutoFilter Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff823161.aspx), 
[Worksheet.Sort Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195963(v=office.15).aspx),

[WorksheetFunction Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I needed, though I see it's no easy workaround.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy old data, Refresh, Copy new data, Remove Duplicates

I would maybe use this approach:

1. Before each new refreshed query, I would copy the existing data to some "All data" sheet.
2. Refresh the From Web Query
3. Copy the new data from step 2 to the "All data" sheet, append on bottom.
4. Remove duplicates.

### Alternatives: HTTP Request or Internet Explorer navigate

Consider instead of Excel import data feature, using *HTTP Request* to get the *Response Text*. Or you can navigate to the site using *Internet Explorer* object.

Then you can assign the *Response Text* to *HTMLDocument* and get the data you need. Or you can use some *Regular expression* to extract it.

Then you can either import all the data and remove duplicates afterwards, or you can scan before importing, to see, if the record does not exists, and import it only then.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I probably didn't make it clear enough in my post, but I want this to run as automatically as possible, and the records are updated every few minutes. So manually copying/removing rows won't work unfortunately.

Comment: @morten, VBA can do that for you. No manual steps are needed. I described a Sub in words.